# Preload joomla page with an animation

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla, preloader

I would like my Joomla! homepage to load completely before it shows up and while it load I would like to show a small .gif animation. I have seen it on Kronos wordpress theme (http://demo.drythemes.com/index.php?theme=kronos-wp). What you see as a preloader on this website is a sample of what I want. How can I implement it in Joomla?

Thanks

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.

Answer (score 0):

Right after the `body` tag place the style below which set the opacity to 0. `page_wrapper` is the div name of the main div. It could be container in Joomla.

```
<body>
<style>
#page_wrapper{
    opacity:0;
}

}
</style>
<div id="loading">
    <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="img/loading.gif">
</div>
<div id="page_wrapper">
 <!-- All your html template goes inside this div.
```

Place this script at the end of the place which enables the page content when whole page is loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#page_wrapper').animate({ opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok this is going to be a very noob question. Where do I put this code in the joomla!? Should I paste this into the html found in template folders? or where? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah in your template folder index.php dude.

Comment: Ok thanks buddy! got it! just one last question. Where do I paste the second part of your code. Where is this 'place' which enables the page content..what does it look like? sorry but I am not a coder. thanks again.

Comment: At the bottom of your index.php

Comment: $ is assigned to mootools in Joomla 2.5, you should use jQuery instead of $ to get it to work so the first line would look like jQuery(window).load(function() {  etc.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I found the code that worked very nicely for me on this link (http://www.gordonmac.com/adding-a-page-loading-box-with-jquery). I modified it to my need to hide the page completely while it loads and display a .gif and if I am not mistaken the tuorial uses the point raised by Riccardo. Just a follow up question. Please see the link and let me know if it is possible to get rid of #loading (preloader screen) when page is 50-60% loaded and not wait until it is completely loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this plugin, it's not in the JED, but I have try it and it works well in Joomla 2.5 and 3.0 http://emkt.mx/joomla-website-preloader-plugin.html It's a Joomla plugin wich starts a loading animation until everything in the page has loaded.